# Mail app on OS X 10.10 goes blank with Office 365 Account after displaying for a minute

Tags: mail.app, email, office-365

I am having an issue viewing email on Office 365 with Mail app.

After clicking on the Office 365 mailbox to read the emails the message list goes blank after about a minute, I then have to click on another mailbox then back to the Office 365 one to view the messages again but you only get about a minute until it does it again. This is frustrating when you are reading a long email.

This only happens with Office 365 accounts, I also use iCloud and Google mail accounts without any problems in Mail.

I have run connection doctor but it says everything is ok.

Has anyone any ideas? Or come across this before?

Comment: Having updated my Mac to El Capitan this issue seems to have been resolved, 3 days using Mail app and no blank mailbox issues.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug which has been around since (if Google is anything to go by) at least OS X 10.8 (!) and is still not fixed. That's modern Apple for you.

None of these worked for me (e.g. the "Rebuild" option is greyed out, for starters!) but maybe they'll help you.

[Mail.app inbox becomes blank after a few minutes of use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73070/mail-app-inbox-becomes-blank-after-a-few-minutes-of-use)